# 1st order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me solve this 1st order linear differential equation 
$$(1+x^2)y'=2 \cosh(y)$$
The answer on the back of the book is 
$$y=\ln\left(\frac{x+c}{1-cx}\right).$$
I found $\arctan(\exp y)= \arctan(x)+c$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Comment on terminology. That equation depends on $\cosh(y)$ and is therefore not linear. A linear differential equation has the form $a_n(x)y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)} + \dots + a_1(x)y' + a_0(x) y = f(x)$ where $y^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative of $y$ and $f, a_n, a_{n-1}\dots a_0$ are functions of $x$. In particular it does not depend on non-linear functions of $y$ or its derivatives.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math problem?

Comment: This may have originated in a physics problem, but in its present state, it's purely math.

Comment: The transformation is elementary. Take the tangent of both members.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is separable :
$$(1+x^2)y'=2 \cosh(y)$$
$$\int \frac {dy}{\cosh(y)}=2 \int \frac {dx}{(1+x^2)}$$
$$\int \frac {e^y}{e^{2y}+1}dy=\int \frac {dx}{(1+x^2)}$$
With $u=e^y \implies du=e^ydy$
$$\int \frac {du}{u^2+1}= \arctan(x)+K $$
$$\arctan(e^y)=\arctan (x)+K$$
Take tangent of both side
$$e^y=\tan (\arctan(x)+K)$$
use the formula $\tan (A+B)=\frac {\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A \tan B}$
$$\implies  e^y=\dfrac {x+C}{1-xC}$$
$$ \boxed {y(x)= \ln \left| \frac {x+C}{1-xC}\right |}$$